# Type error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I made a slider with React and wrote it with typescript. I got such an error, how can I fix this field?

```
useEffect(() => setPosition(-(currentKey * window.innerWidth) + ('px')), [ currentKey ])
```

Here is the error I get in terminal:
Type error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.

I did some research but I couldn't solve this area. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to convert it to a string before setting it in state.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>